# Angular Material Table: How to highlight the column that is being sorted?

Tags: angular-material

Using a Angular Material table. How would be possible to apply a different background color to the column that is being sorted?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the `<th>` to change color on sort, assign a template ref, and reach into the reference to check if sort is active and sort value is present.

```
<th mat-header-cell #header *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header 
[style.background-color]="
(header['_sort'].active == 'id' && header['_sort'].direction) ?'red':''"> ID </th>
```

**StackBlitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fzkja?embed=1&file=app/table-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it but I know a partial solution for your problem, My solution works if and only if the sort is being done by the user i.e. it doesn't highlight the column in initial sorting on first render however I post it here it might give you a direction to what to look at.
In order to capture the sort event you should add an event listener `(matSortChange)="onSortEvent($event)"` to your DOM file as following:

```html
<table (matSortChange)="onSortEvent($event)"  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

then in your `.ts` file you can capture the name of the clicked column using the following and store it in a local variable:

```html
  activeColumn: string;
onSortEvent(eventData){
    this.activeColumn= eventData['active'];
  }
```

This will populate the name of the active column in a local variable which can be in turn used to activate a specific class for your headers like following:
in your css file you can have something like:
`.highlight {
  background-color: lightgray;
}`
and in your DOM file:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [className]="activeColumn === 'position'?'highlight':'default'"> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{}} </td>
 </ng-container>
```

I hope it solves a little bit of your issues.